# Firebase não ordena lista por data corretamente

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Estou filtrando alguns documentos pela data/hora para recuperar os itens mais recentes primeiro.

Porém, ao adicionar um item novo na lista ele é adicionado corretamente, mas ao reiniciar o app a lista é refeita e os itens são organizados de forma aleatória, o que não deveria está acontecendo pois estou ordenando pela data.

Pode ser que seja como estou fazendo para adicionar esses itens na lista.

**Estou fazendo assim:**

```
Future<void> _addListernerFavoritos() async{
  favoritosModel.limparLista();
  List<String> listaBackp = [];

  //aqui é o listen dos meus favoritos
  //onde deveria está filtrando pela data corretamente
  //quando adiciono um favorito novo ele organiza certinho
  //o problema é quando reinicio o app ai que os itens são ordenados de forma aleatória
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("usuarios")
      .doc(usuario.idUsuario)
      .collection("favoritos")
      .orderBy("data", descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((snapshot) {

    snapshot.docChanges.forEach((change) async{
      String idEmpresa = change.doc.id;

      switch (change.type) {
        case DocumentChangeType.added:
        //========== quando um favorito for adicionado ==========

          DocumentSnapshot docEmp = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("empresas")
              .doc(idEmpresa)
              .get();

          Empresa empresa = Empresa.fromDocumentSnapshot(docEmp);
          if(!favoritosModel.listFavoritos.contains(empresa)){
            //favoritosModel.addFavoritos(empresa);
            favoritosModel.insertFavorito(0, empresa);
          }

          break;
        case DocumentChangeType.modified:
        //========== modificado ==========
          break;
        case DocumentChangeType.removed:
        //========== removido ==========
          favoritosModel.removeWhere(idEmpresa);
          listaBackp.add(idEmpresa);
          break;
      }
    });

    //_sort();
  });
}
```

**O model que estou usando pra atualizar a lista é esse:**

```
class FavoritosModel = _FavoritosModel with _$FavoritosModel;

abstract class _FavoritosModel with Store{

  @observable
  ObservableList<Empresa> listFavoritos = ObservableList();

  @action
  void insertFavorito(int index, Empresa value){
    listFavoritos.insert(index, value);
  }

  @action
  void addFavoritos(Empresa value) {
    listFavoritos.add(value);
  }

  @action
  void removeWhere(String idEmpresa){
    listFavoritos.removeWhere((empresa) => idEmpresa == empresa.idEmpresa);
  }

  @action
  void limparLista(){
    listFavoritos.clear();
  }

  @action
  void attEmpresa(int index, Empresa value){
    listFavoritos.removeWhere((empresa) => empresa.idEmpresa == value.idEmpresa);
    listFavoritos.insert(index, value);
  }

}
```

**Meu listView está assim:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      color: Cores.COR_CINZA_BACKGROUND,
      child: Observer(
        builder: (_){
          FavoritosModel favoritosModel = GetIt.I<FavoritosModel>();
          ObservableList<Empresa> listFavoritos = favoritosModel.listFavoritos;

          if(listFavoritos.length == 0){
            return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
              child: Center(
                child: TextApp(
                  text: "Você ainda não adicionou nenhuma empresa aos favoritos",
                  fontSize: 16,
                  textColor: Cores.COR_DARK_LIGTH,
                  fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                  centralizar: true,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            //reverse: true,
            itemCount: listFavoritos.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){

              Empresa empresa = listFavoritos[index];

              if(empresa == null){
                return Container();
              }

              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  push(context, TelaEmpresa(empresa: empresa));
                },
                  child: CardEmpresa(empresa: empresa, favoritos: true,));
            },
          );

        },
      ),
    );

  }
```

Ao meu ver está tudo correto, não entendo o porque não está ordenando pela data.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

**Já tentei salvar a data destas duas formas e nenhuma funciona:**

```
Timestamp getDataFiltro(){
  var now = new Timestamp.now();
  return now;
}

String getDateNow(){
  var now = new DateTime.now();
  return now.toString();
}
```

Comment: Olá, Fiquei com a suspeita que você poderia chamar favoritosModel.sort(); apenas uma vez, logo após o switch()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problema Solucionado.**

Para solucionar esse problema tive que chamar o `favoritosModel.sort();` em todos as changes do listen.

Abaixo deixo o listen com as alterações realizadas para ajudar novas pessoas que tenha esse mesmo problema:

```
Future<void> _addListernerFavoritos() async{
    favoritosModel.limparLista();
    List<String> listaBackp = [];

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("usuarios")
        .doc(usuario.idUsuario)
        .collection("favoritos")
        .orderBy("data", descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {

      snapshot.docChanges.forEach((change) async{
        String idEmpresa = change.doc.id;
        Timestamp dataFiltro = change.doc["data"];

        switch (change.type) {
          case DocumentChangeType.added:
          //========== quando um favorito for adicionado ==========

            DocumentSnapshot docEmp = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("empresas")
                .doc(idEmpresa)
                .get();

            Empresa empresa = Empresa.fromDocumentSnapshot(docEmp);
            empresa.dataFiltro = dataFiltro;
            if(!favoritosModel.listFavoritos.contains(empresa)){
              //favoritosModel.insertFavorito(0, empresa);
            }
            favoritosModel.addFavoritos(empresa);

            favoritosModel.sort();
            break;
          case DocumentChangeType.modified:
          //========== modificado ==========
            favoritosModel.sort();
            break;
          case DocumentChangeType.removed:
          //========== removido ==========
            favoritosModel.removeWhere(idEmpresa);
            favoritosModel.sort();
            listaBackp.add(idEmpresa);
            break;
        }
      });

      favoritosModel.sort();
    });

 }
```

Comment: Jovem, bem vindo ao Stackoverflow...  não vou "downvotar", falo com a maior humildade do mundo... quando lançamos alguma pergunta com recompensa, a brincadeira legal é: Deixar a galera responder. Você respondeu antes do prazo sua própria pergunta, isso quebra a brincadeira porque alguém poderia estar estudando seu problema, mesmo não sendo especialista em Firebase para te ajudar. Mesmo que vc tenha solucionado, agora perdeu a "graça" de alguém responder, inclusive com uma solução melhor.

Comment: Olá Mateus, desculpe por isso. Sou novo por aqui. Mas toda e qualquer melhoria será muito bem vinda. Agradeço sua atenção mas não podia aguardar muito tempo para solucionar esse problema pois tenho tempo de entrega. Obrigado pela sua ajuda e qualquer sugestão estarei aqui.